# Pentaho Spoon unable to connect to IBM DB2 database due to a missing'driver (jar file)

Tags: db2, pentaho-spoon

I'm using Pentaho's Spoon. When I try and connect to a IBM DB2 database I get the below error

> `Driver class 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'IBM DB2' driver (jar file) is installed.
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver

I searched on google but could not find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IBM Data Server Drivers can be downloaded from the related [support page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21385217) or the [overall download page](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/Downloads/Software/Information_Management/IBM_Data_Server_Client_Packages). The links can be found by Google or in the [DB2 Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_t0010264.html).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today. 
Though the error message says what needs to be done:

`Driver class 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'IBM DB2' driver (jar file) is installed.
com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver`

One still needs additional information to fix this.

Get the exact driver from Pentaho's [JDBC drivers reference.](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.0/Setup/JDBC_Drivers_Reference) 
Once you download it; put the appropriate `.jars` in the `lib` directory of Pentaho's tool. In my case, I'm using Spoon on windows

so the location would be:

`C:\PathToWhereSpoonIsRunningFrom\pdi-ce-8.2.0.0-342\data-integration\lib`

the files would be:

`db2jcc.jar
db2jcc4.jar
db2jcc_license_cu.jar`

Full error message:

```
Error connecting to database [Your_Database_Connection_Name] :org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Driver class 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'IBM DB2' driver (jar file) is installed.
com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Driver class 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'IBM DB2' driver (jar file) is installed.
com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver


    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:472)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:370)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:341)
    .
    .
    .
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Driver class 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'IBM DB2' driver (jar file) is installed.
com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver

    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:515)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:456)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:490)
    ... 57 more

Hostname: YourHostname
Port: YourPortNumber
Database name: YourDBName
```